# python: Dictionary counter items. How to optimize performance

Tags: python, dictionary, counter

I need to keep track of occurrences of items in parsed files in a structure as follows:

```
data= {'tomate': {'John': 2, 'mike': 2},
 'pasta': {'mike': 1},
 'wine': {'mike': 1, 'alex': 2}}
```

the dictionary starts as empty one. data = {} and its is being populated with values when they are not there and adding up users +1 if the user is there or =1 if the user is not yet there.

This is my code:

```
def modify(data, key, client):
try:
    # if both keys are there
    data[key][client] = data[key][client] +1
    #print(f"{key} is there. {client} is there.")
except:
    try: 
        data[key][client] = 1
        #print(f"{client} not there, but {key}")
    except:
        data[key]={}
        data[key][client] = 1
        #print(f"{client} and {key} added")
return data
```

It works:

```
key="wine"
client = "alex"
modify(d, key, client)
```

giving:

```
{'tomate': {'John': 2, 'mike': 2},
 'pasta': {'mike': 1},
 'wine': {'mike': 1, 'alex': 3}}
```

The question is if using try/except is not the way to go, i.e. not pythonic, because I am relying on exceptions for the code to work properly which I feel is a little bit weird and might make the whole code much slower.

Is there any other option to keep track of a counter like this that I might have a look to that might be faster?
Performance is very important of course since I have to count hundreds of millions of times.

---

EDIT 1:
Evaluating the speed of a proposed solution I have this comparison that strikes me since my solution is faster (and I would not expect that):

[image]

EDIT 2:
This question has been closed despite of very well elaborated answers and being directed to finding a proper way to solve a problem. It is really annoying that people just close questions like this. How can someone say that this questions is opinion-based if we are talking about computing times?

Comment: If you have working code you are looking to improve, consider asking this on Code Review instead.

Comment: @TylerH, this looks too much like _example code_ to be suitable for Review.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Better to 'try' something and catch the exception or test if it's possible first to avoid an exception?](/q/7604636/90527), [Check if a given key already exists in a dictionary and increment it](/q/473099/90527)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With try/except version, the search for index is done only once (most of the time). It serves both the purpose of checking the presence of index, and altering the associated value. That is why your version is the fastest so far. Last one-liner from Andrej is very fast also, especially with lot of new indexes (because then, your version spend some time in except, whereas Andrej's one-liner doesn't really care)

One notable, seemingly minor but important improvement to your version could be:

```py
def modify(data, key, client):
try:
    # if both keys are there
    data[key][client] += 1
    #print(f"{key} is there. {client} is there.")
except:
    try: 
        data[key][client] = 1
        #print(f"{client} not there, but {key}")
    except:
        data[key]={}
        data[key][client] = 1
        #print(f"{client} and {key} added")
return data
```

Yes, just that `+=` changes quite a lot. Especially with lot of "updates" (I mean, not new index). Because `x=x+1` means that python needs to figure out what is `x` twice. Whereas `x+=1` finds the l-value only once. Which is roughly the same usually. Except when finding the place itself is a non-negligible part of the cost. As it is here, with indexation

Some benchmarking on big sets of generated data
Experiment 1: data with lot of new indexes.

| Version | time |
| --- | --- |
| Yours | 5.11 |
| Mine (that is yours with +=) | 4.44 |
| Andrej's 2-liner | 6.21 |
| Andrej/Yevhen's if-else | 5.69 |
| Get based | 5.99 |
| Andrej's one-liner | 5.08 |

Experiment 2, with lots of collisions (that is not new index. That is other than 1 values...)

| Version | time |
| --- | --- |
| Yours | 5.43 |
| My += | 4.67 |
| Andrej's 2-liner | 6.73 |
| if/else | 6.23 |
| .get | 6.51 |
| Andrej's 1-liner | 5.60 |

So, in both cases, your version, upgraded with my += suggestion, is the fastest. If lot of new indexes, then Andrej's one-liner slightly beats your version (without +=). If lot of existing indexes, it is roughly the same (again, because then you use more except clauses for new indexes).

`+=` improvement make your version the best in any cases.

Answer (score 4):

You can rewrite the function using `if-else` or using `dict.setdefault` and get rid of Exceptions:

```py
def modify(data, key, client):
    data.setdefault(key, {}).setdefault(client, 0)
    data[key][client] += 1


data = {}

modify(data, "tomate", "John")
modify(data, "tomate", "John")
modify(data, "tomate", "mike")
modify(data, "tomate", "mike")
modify(data, "pasta", "mike")
modify(data, "wike", "mike")
modify(data, "wike", "alex")
modify(data, "wike", "alex")

print(data)
```

Prints:

```
{
    "tomate": {"John": 2, "mike": 2},
    "pasta": {"mike": 1},
    "wike": {"mike": 1, "alex": 2},
}
```

---

Using `if-else`:

```py
def modify(data, key, client):
    if key not in data:
        data[key] = {}

    if client in data[key]:
        data[key][client] += 1
    else:
        data[key][client] = 1
```

---

EDIT: One-liner version:

```py
def modify(data, key, client):
    x[client] = (x := data.setdefault(key, {})).get(client, 0) + 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Very elegant two liner. I am really surprise that this method takes a bit longer than the one with Exceptions. (See editing in the quesion)

Comment: @JFerro You can try one-liner version I've just add to my answer. But personally I'd go with `if-else` version in production code - readability counts.

Answer (score 2):

One step to a more pythonic solution is to catch exception that you want to catch (instead of any exception):

```
try:
   ...
except KeyError:
   ...
```

Second, you can check whether the element is in the dictionary instead of `try`ing:

```
if key not in data:
    data[key] = {}
if client not in data[key]:
    data[key][client] = 0
data[ket][client] += 1
```

You can also use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) that does these checks for you. In my experience and experiments all these solutions a very close in terms of execution time so choose which one looks better for you.

Answer (score 0):

The bare `except` is dangerous: there are other reasons for exceptions to be thrown (user interrupt, out of memory, ...).  Catch the specific exception, but beware that both `data[key]` and `data[key][client]` can throw, so you'll want to identify which level needs inserting.

Consider using a `defaultdict` to insert any needed key, and a `Counter` to track how many orders each client has:

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

data= defaultdict(Counter,
                  {'tomate': Counter({'John': 2, 'mike': 2}),
                   'pasta': Counter({'mike': 1}),
                   'wine': Counter({'mike': 1, 'alex': 2})})

def modify(data, key, client):
    data[key][client] += 1
```